# Cron "Running" But "Not Running"!! How to fix this?

Tags: cron, cron-job, scheduled-job

I had everything running fine until this morning all of a sudden CiviCRM decided to show up a message that cron is not running. But if I go to scheduled Job its all running fine. Please see the screenshot. I have not installed anything nor have changed settings on host. Cant find anything in the log either! What could go wrong? I am puzzled, Can anyone help please? Thanks

I am on CiviCRM 5.17.5, drupal 7
Here is my cpanel cron setting:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/ea-php72 /home/webadmin/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u soap -p Bd88khdksjfh -e Job -a execute
```

[image: ron]

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the admin password for Drupal?

Comment: Nothing changed. I had to manually execute send scheduled mailing, and didn’t receive the warning. Not sure if this going to happen again on next mass mailings activity.

Comment: This happened on my instance as well!